# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ajaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint'

Tags: java, xml, spring

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ajaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint' defined in file [C:*****\controllers\filters\AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected single matching bean but found 5: dslDecryptKeyStorePass,dslDecryptTrustStorePass,dslDecryptKeyStorePassDEV,dslDecryptTrustStorePassDEV,dslDecryptSolacePass

BEAN CONFIGURATION in XML:
***removed the tags***

bean id="authEntryPoint" class="****.controllers.filters.AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" scope="singleton"
property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html"
bean

CODE:
public class AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

```
public AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
    super(loginFormUrl);
}

public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"))) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access Denied");
    } else {
        super.commence(request, response, authException);
    }
}
```

}

I have a bean that is defined in xml and Im getting the error above, does anyone know how to fix it? i upgraded from spring 3 to 5.6 now. Im trying to run but having trouble

Comment: There is no property named `loginFormUrl` it has a constructor argument instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.